# refetch usequery when go back to previous screen not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-apollo

I have 2 page, Page A (current page) and page B (next page). I am  using `react-native-router-flux` as navigation. When go back to page A from page B (`Actions.pop()`) i want to refetch usequery so i put code like this in page A or component A

```
const { loading, data, refetch: refetchData } = useQuery(QUERY_GET_STATUS, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });
  
useEffect(() => {
   if(refresh){
    refetchData();
  }
}, [refresh])
```

variable `refresh` is redux state has value `true`  and `false`. Before go back to page A `refresh` state will be update first into `true`. but i found the issue that refetch query not working. Do you have any solution to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna call function every time when screen on front then you this hook

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React{useCallback} from 'react'


 useFocusEffect(
   useCallback(() => {
     //function
    }, [])
  );
```

Comment: Do you have any solution when using `react-native-router-flux` as navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different package. I'm not totally sure if this might work for you but I think with `react-native-router-flux`, you have access to `currentScene`. So you could add an effect that is called whenever the route changes

```
const currentScene = Actions.currentScene;
useEffect(() => {
   if(refresh && currentScene === "whatever-scene-you-are-on"){
    refetchData();
  }
}, [refresh, currentScene])
```